# Using append, clone in loop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, append, clone

I'm trying to create a few divs with for loop. I'm using .append() and .clone methods but order of div is wrong. Even when I created div before loop, in index.html first div (class news0) is generated after last div (class news3) which should be the last one. How can I solve this?

```
    $news.ready(function () {
        var query = [];
        console.log(query);
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUri + "news",
            data: {q: query},
            success: showNews
        });
        return false;
    });

    function showNews(response) {
        var news = response[0];
        console.log(news);
        $news.append($div);
        $div.attr('class', 'news' + 0);
        $div.append($h1);
        $div.append($h2);
        $div.append($h3);
        $div.append($p);

        $h1.html(news.title);
        $h2.html(news.author);
        $h3.html(news.date);
        $p.html(news.body);

        for (var i = 1; i < response.length; i++) {
            news = response[i];

            $news.append($div.clone());
            $div.attr('class', 'news' + i);
            $div.append($h1);
            $div.append($h2);
            $div.append($h3);
            $div.append($p);

            $h1.html(news.title);
            $h2.html(news.author);
            $h3.html(news.date);
            $p.html(news.body);
        }
    }
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The order of the `divs` in your case is not appropriate because of the asynchronous nature of the javascript for loop. what you can do is use `$.each` function in jquery which is `synchronous` and hence will give you the desired output

Your function with `$.each()` loop will be like

```
function showNews(response) {
    var news = response[0];
    console.log(news);
    $news.append($div);
    $div.attr('class', 'news' + 0);
    $div.append($h1);
    $div.append($h2);
    $div.append($h3);
    $div.append($p);

    $h1.html(news.title);
    $h2.html(news.author);
    $h3.html(news.date);
    $p.html(news.body);

    $.each(reponse, function(index, news){
       if(index > 0) {
       $news.append($div.clone());
       $div.attr('class', 'news' + i);
       $div.append($h1);
       $div.append($h2);
       $div.append($h3);
       $div.append($p);

      $h1.html(news.title);
      $h2.html(news.author);
      $h3.html(news.date);
      $p.html(news.body);
      }

  })

}
```

Comment: This doesn't sovle the problem. Now i have 4 divs but first is empty.

Comment: Unfortunetly, order of divs again is 3 - 0 - 1 - 2.